# Fill dots of UIPage Control when I scroll tutorial

Tags: swift, highlight, fill, uipagecontrol

I want to highlight(fill) the dots of UIPageControl when I scroll not to move dot to the next one.
Is there any way to do that.

Expected [image: expected] VS Reality[image: Reality]

Thanks,